# Purple Screen of Death w/New AMD Card

Tags: 17.10, radeon, amd-graphics, vulkan

**Old setup:** Ubuntu 17.10 with an Nvidia GPU and `nvidia-387` drivers.

**New setup:** Ubuntu 17.10 with a Radeon Rx550 (the Nvidia card removed) and the following drivers:

```
sudo apt install mesa-vulkan-drivers vulkan-utils
```

**The problem:** Launching Ubuntu now results in the purple screen of death after leaving the Ubuntu boot menu.

**NOTE:** I didn't uninstall the `nvidia-387` drivers; is it safe to have them both on my system at once?

Comment: I would remove the unneeded `nvidia` drivers just to keep the system cleaner if for no other reason.

Answer (score 3):

## AMDGPU-PRO driver doesn't support Ubuntu 17.10

From this [AMD tech support website](https://community.amd.com/thread/221419) an employee named Matt says:

> We don't support Ubuntu 17 yet in the latest AMDGPU-Pro, use 16.04.03
>   and Kernel 4.10 and Xorg 1.19.

## Install AMDGPU-PRO Linux driver under Ubuntu 16.04

From the [AMD website](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Driver-for-Linux-Release-Notes.aspx) instructions for installing under Ubuntu 16.04 are listed:

- Edit `/etc/default/grub` as root and modify GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT in order to add "amdgpu.vm_fragment_size=9" (without the quotes). The line may look something like this after the change:

  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash amdgpu.vm_fragment_size=9"`
- Update grub and reboot as root:

  `update-grub;reboot`

## Your card is verified as AMDGPU-PRO compatible

The AMDGPU-Pro Driver is compatible with the following AMD products.

#### AMD Product Family Compatibility

```
Radeon™ RX Vega Series Graphics             AMD Radeon™ Pro WX-series
Radeon™ Vega Frontier Edition               AMD FirePro™ W9100
Radeon™ RX 550/560/570/580 Series Graphics  AMD FirePro™ W8100
AMD Radeon™ RX 460/470/480 Graphics         AMD FirePro™ W7100
AMD Radeon™ Pro Duo                         AMD FirePro™ W5100
AMD Radeon™ R9 Fury/Fury X/Nano Graphics    AMD FirePro™ W4300
AMD Radeon™ R9 380/380X/390/390X Graphics   AMD FirePro™ W4100
AMD Radeon™ R9 285/290/290X Graphics        AMD FirePro™ W2100
AMD Radeon™ R7 240/250/250X/260/260X/350    AMD FirePro™ W600
AMD Radeon™ HD7700/7800/8500/8600           AMD FirePro™ S-Series
AMD Radeon™ R9 360 Graphics                 AMD Radeon™ Pro WX 9100
AMD Radeon™ R5 340
```

Comment: But isn't the `amdgpu-pro` driver completely distinct from `mesa-vulkan-drivers`? I need `mesa-vulkan-drivers` specifically to work since I'm trying to get SteamVR running on Linux (which isn't compatible with `amdgpu-pro` AFAIK).

Comment: @user1770201 on the website link I posted it says: **OpenGL, OpenCL™, and Vulkan™ drivers provided by this download.  Open source software is also provided** but I don't have an AMD card to test it.

Comment: AFAIK, AMDGPU-PRO is in the process of being open-sourced but isn't yet compatible with (i) Ubuntu 17.10 as well as (ii) SteamVR.

Comment: @user1770201 Yes AMDGPU-PRO only supports Ubuntu 16.04 as the highest version so far. You **probably** can still run Kernel 4.14.13 if you want best hardware performance and support though. My own system is a combination of some older stable stuff and leading-edge last week stuff. It's up to you and I was just trying to let people know what is out there.