# Ubuntu installation does not detect hard drive but shows in GParted - ubuntu live usb

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive

I was previously running Windows 7 on my system but due to a "bootable device not found error" in windows 7, I decided to install Ubuntu afresh. I had performed all tests and checks of hard drive, processors etc. using the HP recovery utility - all components passed all checks. So apparently, no hardware issue.

Next, I booted Ubuntu from live USB and as I could access drives using Ubuntu, I backed up my data and deleted all existing partitions using GParted.

Now, it looks like this:
[Gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHCYE.png)

I  have 2 hard drives - sda (see screenshot - 500 GB ) and sdb (28GB with intel rapid start technology - i plan to leave this drive as it is)

sda1 - the boot partition from windows 7. I have not changed this

sda2 - i removed all existing partitions and merged into this. I want to install Ubuntu on this partition.

Now, When I run the Ubuntu Installer it does not detect sda. The installer only shows sdc (the usb flash drive)

Other information:
I do not have any option of RAID in my BIOS. 
My system is running in legacy mode.

sudo fdisk -l detects the drives:

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.9 GiB, 1987817472 bytes, 3882456 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 88.5 MiB, 92778496 bytes, 181208 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 54.4 MiB, 57069568 bytes, 111464 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 42.8 MiB, 44879872 bytes, 87656 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 149.9 MiB, 157184000 bytes, 307000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 4 MiB, 4218880 bytes, 8240 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 14.8 MiB, 15462400 bytes, 30200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 1008 KiB, 1032192 bytes, 2016 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x60e00953

Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *      2048    409599    407552   199M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       409600 976773119 976363520 465.6G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/sdb: 29.8 GiB, 32017047552 bytes, 62533296 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x961bffdf

Device     Boot Start     End Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 8386559 8384512   4G 84 OS/2 hidden or Intel hibernation


Disk /dev/sdc: 7.6 GiB, 8178892800 bytes, 15974400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x5092863d

Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1  *          0 4067999 4068000    2G  0 Empty
/dev/sdc2       3989132 3994059    4928  2.4M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)


Disk /dev/loop8: 3.7 MiB, 3825664 bytes, 7472 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the Ubuntu installer from your Live USB.  Go to the bottom of the installer menu and select "do something else."  You should see sda2 from there.  Note that in your Gparted output image, you are showing that 8+GB is being used.  You can overwrite this, or you can go back and use GParted to put that data in its own partition, and then install Ubuntu in an empty one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wasn't getting the "do something else option before", it appeared this time!  However, it is stuck now on restarting after installation. On purple screen. I think it has to do with the AMD Radeon GPU. Any workaround this? To disable the GPU? Thanks in advance

Comment: I looked into that briefly just now.  The latest driver from AMD, 18.4, work with the current LTS version of Ubuntu.  It has instructions for installing the driver on a working system.  Somebody probably knows how to do a new install with it.  --  I suggest you accept this answer, as you go the installation up and the drive detected, and then post a new question specifically about doing a new install on a system with an AMD Radeon - as your description exactly matches the problem reports I found.  https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-prorad-lin-18-40

Comment: Here's an example problem report: https://askubuntu.com/questions/993931/purple-screen-of-death-w-new-amd-card

Comment: My AMD Radeon has gone into legacy unsupported mode, so the new software won't work. I guess I will have to deactivate it permanently. Thanks a  lot though :D

Comment: Disabled the dedicated AMD graphics card by "sudo nano /etc/default/grub" and  "radeon.modeset=0".